# Can I launch a lower version to App Store than previously?

Tags: ios, app-store

I inherited an iOS application where the version is 20.0.0 (Looks like launched with a typo).  I was wondering if I can lower the version down to 3.0.0?

Comment: What happened when you _tried_ it? I'm sorry, but it always amazes me when people ask questions where simple experimentation would have revealed the answer. Why is everybody so gormless? Will the universe explode if they just test stuff?

Comment: I tried it in XCode, and it gave me a "Version must be higher" error when I tried to upload it.

Comment: So you already knew the answer. Which raises another question: why can't people just believe their own eyes? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a word, no. Version numbers can only go up. If you attempt to upload a binary with a lower version number, iTunes Connect will balk.

Comment: You might be able to work around the issue by contacting Apple directly. There are certain things they can manipulate by hand, on request, and this might be one of them.

Comment: Thanks! It will be really interesting to hear what happens.

Comment: I reached out and they didn't seem to answer my question correctly.  I am assuming this can't be done from a logical perspective as well

Comment: Thanks for reporting back. I guess this is just immutable and you're stuck with the version number you've got, unless you want to abandon this app and start with a new bundle ID.

Comment: Does that include Testflight? If on Testflight you have binary 4 version 1.4, can you upload binary 5 version 1.0 for the app store version? Just wondering

Comment: No, they are both the same place. You can only go up. You cannot go from 1.4 to 1.0.